# Inserting data in mysql with shell script

Tags: mysql, sql, bash, shell

I have a problem with a shell script:

I am trying to inject data from a source file containing MySQL queries into a data base. Here are the relevant lines of my shell script:

```
mysql -u root
source /usr/local/insert.sql;
quit;
```

For example I am running the file as `./insertfile` and it is running smoothly but when it comes to data insertion in MySQL it is logging into MySQL using the `mysql -u root` command but the remaining operations (`source /usr/local/insert.sql;` and `quit;`) are not being executed. When I quit MySQL manually it tries to execute the rest of the command from my `insert.sql` file.

So please help me use the right shell script so that I can insert the queries from the source file.

Comment: do you have full rights on the file on operation system level - and make sure that you run 'USE DB_NAME;' before running it

Comment: What type of permission are you talking about sir?

Comment: at the file system level !

Comment: Yes I do have those permissions.

Comment: ok ! go inside your mysql and run this commnad '\! head /usr/local/insert.sql' -- show me the output !

Comment: `mysql> \! head /usr/local/insert.sql
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS insert;
USE insert;

CREATE TABLE tourque (
  table_name varchar(50) unique,
  next_id decimal(18,0)
);

insert into tourque values('tbInsert',1);
` showing like this

Comment: ok ! thx - it seams you that your import hands

Comment: you 'insert ' database is present on the database ? is soo run 'show processlist' to see if any lock are present

Comment: @Shah9il Do not edit other user's answers to reflect what you specifically did. If you think it will help others looking at the question, you can instead post that as an answer or edit it in after your question.

Comment: Thanks Mr.BroSlow actually I am a newbie here... I will keep that in mind next time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your help. I have tried adding your line in my script and it was primarily giving some errors then I changed the command like below -

`mysql -u root --execute="source /usr/local/insert.sql; \q"`

Above line helped me to execute my command.

Thanks to all for being this much helpful.

Regards,
Shah9il

Answer (score 1):

One way to do that would be

```
mysql -u root --execute="source /usr/local/insert.sql; quit;"
```

Comment: Dear zshooter sir, Thanks for your valuable comment but after adding this link in my script the following error is showing in mysql `ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'quit' at line 1
` Please help me with that also

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your import hangs ! 
Check for lock on your database.

```
show processlist;
```

Run FLUSH TABLES to release any possible locks and then run your import command.
**if source command hangs again :**

- Enter your myslq server
- drop database insert;
- create database insert
- exit the mysql server and run:

  mysqldump -u -p database-name < dump.sql

Comment: The issue is not solved after flusing and also after dropping the database and creating again